# Why can't I scrape table data in order?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to scrape table data off of this website:

https://www.nfl.com/standings/league/2019/REG

I have working code (below), however, it seems like the table data is not in the order that I see on the website.

On the website I see (top-down):
`Baltimore Ravens, Green Bay Packers, ..., Cincinatti Bengals`

But in my code results, I see (top-down): `Bengals, Lions, ..., Ravens`

Why is soup returning the tags out of order? Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import lxml

url = 'https://www.nfl.com/standings/league/2019/REG'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
print(soup) #not sure why soup isn't returning tags in the order I see on website
table = soup.table

headers = []
for th in table.select('th'):
    headers.append(th.text)
    
print(headers)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

for sup in table.select('sup'):
  sup.decompose() #Removes sup tag from the table tree so x, xz* in nfl_team_name will not show up

for tr in table.select('tr')[1:]:
    td_list = tr.select('td')
    td_str_list = [td_list[0].select('.d3-o-club-shortname')[0].text]
    td_str_list = td_str_list + [td.text for td in td_list[1:]]
    df.loc[len(df)] = td_str_list
    
print(df.to_string())
```

Answer (score 1):

After initial load the table is dynamically sorted by column `PCT` - To get your goal do the same with your `DataFrame` using `sort_values()`:

```
pd.read_html('https://www.nfl.com/standings/league/2019/REG')[0].sort_values(by='PCT',ascending=False)
```

Or based on your example:

```
df.sort_values(by='PCT',ascending=False)
```

Output:

| NFL Team | W | L | T | PCT | PF | PA | Net Pts | Home | Road | Div | Pct | Conf | Pct | Non-Conf | Strk | Last 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ravens | 14 | 2 | 0 | 0.875 | 531 | 282 | 249 | 7 - 1 - 0 | 7 - 1 - 0 | 5 - 1 - 0 | 0.833 | 10 - 2 - 0 | 0.833 | 4 - 0 - 0 | 12W | 5 - 0 - 0 |
| 49ers | 13 | 3 | 0 | 0.813 | 479 | 310 | 169 | 6 - 2 - 0 | 7 - 1 - 0 | 5 - 1 - 0 | 0.833 | 10 - 2 - 0 | 0.833 | 3 - 1 - 0 | 2W | 3 - 2 - 0 |
| Saints | 13 | 3 | 0 | 0.813 | 458 | 341 | 117 | 6 - 2 - 0 | 7 - 1 - 0 | 5 - 1 - 0 | 0.833 | 9 - 3 - 0 | 0.75 | 4 - 0 - 0 | 3W | 4 - 1 - 0 |
| Packers | 13 | 3 | 0 | 0.813 | 376 | 313 | 63 | 7 - 1 - 0 | 6 - 2 - 0 | 6 - 0 - 0 | 1 | 10 - 2 - 0 | 0.833 | 3 - 1 - 0 | 5W | 5 - 0 - 0 |

...